# Como funciona internamente as funções de ordenação por callback?

Tags: array, classificação

No php, quando queremos ordenar um `array` de maneira costumizada podemos utilizar a função `usort`.

Sei que para essa função funcionar, devemos utilizar valores `1`, `0` e `-1`.

No caso, se eu quisesse ordenar esse `array` abaixo em ordem decrescente, poderíamos fazer assim:

```
$array[0]['preco'] = 10.00;
$array[1]['preco'] = 25.00;
$array[2]['preco'] = 20.00;


usort($array, function ($a, $b)
{ 
     return $b['preco'] > $a['preco'] ? 1 : 0;
});
```

O resultado seria:

```
[
     [
       "preco" => 25.0,
     ],
     [
       "preco" => 20.0,
     ],
     [
       "preco" => 10.0,
     ],
   ]
]
```

Se invertesse as variáveis na comparação, o resultado seria diferente:

```
  usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
        $a['preco'] > $b['preco'] ? 1 : 0;
  });
```

O resultado seria:

```
[
     [
       "preco" => 10.0,
     ],
     [
       "preco" => 20.0,
     ],
     [
       "preco" => 25.0,
     ],
   ]
```

Costumo também reduzir a comparação simplesmente fazendo uma operação de subtração, quando quero ordenar reversamente:

```
   usort($array, function ($a, $b)
   {
       return $b['preco'] - $a['preco'];
   });
```

Sei que, se utilizássemos o valor `0` para todas as comparações, os resultados se manteriam na mesma posição.

Sei como fazer para mudar a ordenação dos valores, mas não entendo como o php faz isso internamente.

E é possível fazer essa operação em `Python` também.

Exemplo:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]

lista.sort(lambda a,b: b-a)

#[3, 2, 1]
```

Como é feita essa comparação, para que as linguagens sabiam qual é o primeiro e qual é o segundo?

O que representa o `1` ou o `-1`, internamente, para essas funções de ordenação?

Comment: Da pra usar a espaçonave :D nessa função ai. Não faltou a tag do php aí?

Comment: @rray não, por que o `Python` também faz a mesma coisa.

Comment: E quem deu negativo, poderia explicar como eu posso melhorar a pergunta?

Comment: Entendi, achei q era de php a pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O programador não tem acesso ao algoritmo que a linguagem usa para ordenar, e isso provavelmente depende da implementação.

Mas seja qual for o algoritmo de ordenação, ele funciona por comparação de pares de elementos do conjunto a ser ordenado (não digo *todos* funcionam assim, mas pelo menos os mais conhecidos). É por isso que o callback recebe dois argumentos (um par de elementos) e retorna como eles se comparam entre si, sendo:

- `-1` (ou outro negativo) se `a` for menor que `b` (i.e., `a` deve ficar antes de `b`).
- `0` se os elementos forem iguais ou equivalentes.
- `1` (ou outro positivo) se `b` for menor que `a` (i.e., `b` deve ficar antes de `a`).

O callback te dá a oportunidade de ordenar pelo critério que quiser: por uma propriedade de objeto, por uma composição de valores, qualquer coisa. Você decide o que vem primeiro em cada par. A linguagem pega essa informação e coloca o conjunto na ordem que você decidiu, usando determinado algoritmo que ela implementa internamente.

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre o funcionamento dos algoritmos de ordenação mais conhecidos (merecem uma pergunta cada), mas as ilustrações abaixo mostram claramente como eles operam comparando pares de elementos. Repare nas indicações em vermelho.

#### [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

> [image: bubble sort]

#### [Merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

> [image: merge sort]]

#### [Heap sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)

> [image: heap sort]

#### [Quick sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

> [image: quick sort]

Comment: Esse site aqui também tem umas animações bacanas: [sorting algorithms](http://toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms).