# Como ordenar um select option por ordem alfabética com jquery?

Tags: jquery, classificação

Tenho um select option a listar através de um `each` em jquery o que pretendo fazer agora e ordenar esse `each` por ordem alfabética quando listado.

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-add-agent-proximo", function(e) {
if($('#add_agent').is(':checked')){ 
  $('#modal-add-agent').modal('hide'); 

  var id_agente_pai = <?= Auth::user()->id ?>

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "admin/list_agent",
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
      data: { id_agente_pai : 'id_agente_pai'},
      dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function( data ) {
      $.each(data.parents, function( key, parents ) {
          $('#parent').append('<option value="'+parents.id+'"><span>ID('+parents.id+') </span>'+parents.username+'</option>');
      });
      $.each(data.currencies, function( key, currencies ) {
          $('#currency').append('<option value="'+currencies.id+'">'+currencies.code+'</option>');
      });
      $.each(data.funcoes, function( key, funcoes ) {
          $('#funcoes').append('<option value="'+funcoes.id+'">'+funcoes.nome+'</option>');
      });

  }).fail(function(data) {
      toastr.error('Ocorreu um erro!');
  });

  $('#modal-add-agent-modal').modal('show');

  $('#modal-add-agent-modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#parent').empty();
    $('#currency').empty();
    $('#funcoes').empty();
  });

}else if($('#add_jogador').is(':checked')){ 
  $('#modal-add-agent').modal('hide'); 

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "admin/list_agent",
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
      data: { id_agente_pai : 'id_agente_pai'},
      dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function( data ) {
      $.each(data.parents, function( key, parents_jogador ) {
          $('#parent_jogador').append('<option value="'+parents_jogador.id+'"><span>ID('+parents_jogador.id+') </span>'+parents_jogador.username+'</option>');
      });

  }).fail(function(data) {
      toastr.error('Ocorreu um erro!');
  });

  $('#modal-add-jogador-modal').modal('show');

  $('#modal-add-jogador-modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#parent_jogador').empty();
  });
}
});
```

O que pretendo listar e o select com o `id` parents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez simplesmente usando `sort` resolva seu problema!

```
data.parents.sort(function (a, b) {

     if (a.username === b.username) return 0;

     return a.username > b.username ? 1 : -1;
})

$.each(data.parent, function () {
   // ...
});
```

A função `sort` utiliza como `callback` uma função anônima que compara os valores de `username`. Os valores do `array` serão ordenados de acordo com  os retornos `1`, `-1` ou `0`.

Leia mais aqui: [Como funciona internamente as funções de ordenação por callback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120776/como-funciona-internamente-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-por-callback/138135#138135)

Comment: Não resolveu não ordena

Comment: @CésarSousa agora que vi a estrutura do seu `array`, vou editar...

Comment: Agora funcionou bem e mesmo isso obrigado vou ler a essa documentação sobre isso

Comment: Fico feliz que isso tenha resolvido o problema. Considere votar ou marcar  a resposta como útil, para que outros usuários possam se beneficiar da sua pergunta.

Comment: E o que vou fazer obrigado mesmo